# Can we see code changes without restarting blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am using 5.0 BB JDE. 
Is there any way around to see your code changes without restarting BB simulator every time. Or any way to see your changes in less time.
Right now i have to restart my project every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no other option than to restart simulator.

I use JDE + Eclipse and my usual workflow is:

1. Make code changes in Eclipse.
2. Build with JDE (add new files if any).
3. Restart the simulator (simulator that is bundled with JDE loads new .cod automatically on restart, for other simulator I have to manually upload new .cod after restart).

I don't run the project from JDE since it takes too long to attach debugger, while actually I need debugger very rarely.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to restart your simulator just run your project after applying the changes.It load new .cod automatically.